# spring-boot: inside jar file and how is it executed

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, jar

I am currently developing the spring boot application with maven and eclipse.
-when I build the app, txt file under resources folder will be included in jar file?
and can I exclude it from jar?
-when I run the app from eclipse, what command will be executed?
does it mean executing jar file ?

thank you.

Comment: Why do you put a file into the resources if you don't want it in the JAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I build the app, txt file under resources folder will be included in jar file? and can I exclude it from jar?

Don't put files in the resources folder you don't want to have in the classpath and the executable jar.

> when I run the app from eclipse, what command will be executed? does it mean executing jar file ?

Depending on how you execute it - it will either run the main method of your `SpringBootApplication` class or run the Maven goal `spring-boot:run`